# Number of functions $ f : \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\} \to \{a, b, c\} $ such that $ f\left(7\right) \in f\left[\{1, 2, 3\}\right] $

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I need to find the number of functions $ f : \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\} \to \{a, b, c\} $ such that $ f\left(7\right) \in f\left[\{1, 2, 3\}\right] $. Why are my calculations wrong?

The total number of functions is $ 3^7 = 2187 $. We want to subtract the number of functions for which $ f\left(7\right) \notin f\left[\{1, 2, 3\}\right] $. There are $ 3 $ possible ways to choose $ f\left(7\right) $. After we choose it, we have two possible images for each of the elements in the set $ \{1, 2, 3\} $. Therefore, we need to subtract $ 3\cdot2^3\cdot 3^4 = 1944 $. $ 2187 - 1944 = 243 $.

Comment: @talopi  your value seems too small.  After all, there are $3^6$ functions here for which $f(7)=f(1)$ so we know the answer is $>3^6=729$.  i suggest, work by cases.  Start with the case for which $|f(\{1,2,3\})|=3$.

Comment: @Piquito Unfortunately, some times $f(1)=f(2)$, and then you won't have three options for what $f(7)$ can be. So the true answer must be a little less than that.

Comment: @Arthur: Thank you very much. I did not understand teh simbol $f\left(7\right) \in f\left[\{1, 2, 3\}\right]$. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is completely correct; you just made the mistake of counting the images of $7$ twice—the $3\cdot2^3\cdot3^{\color{red}4}$ to be subtracted should be $3\cdot2^3\cdot3^{\color{red}3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!